# Sending form without mail client

Tags: forms, scripting, email, client

everubody! can you help me with my trouble? I'm trying to create form for filling resume. User should not use mail client to submit form. How can I realize this idea on javascript or PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: You need a server based script. Without any server interaction, no mail can be sent.

PHP has a [mail() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and it works very well, if your server administrator enabled it.
Very simple example:

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

If mail() is disabled, you need to connect a SMTP server with correct credentials and then you can send mails via this connection.
This function is implemented in the emailer module of phpBB2 e.g.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the form as a file upload... You can just upload the cv to the webserver and then use your application to send an Email using your account.